# In my haml file, I want to include a link within a string that is coming from a yml file

Tags: hyperlink, yaml, haml

Here's my situation:

I have this in my haml file, ...it's a start:

```
.image-credits
    %div
        %h2
            = t(:image_credits)
        %ul
            %li
                %p
                    = t(:photographer_1)
```

And then in my yml file I have these strings defined:

```
  image_credits : "Image Credits"
  photographer_1 : "\"Miss Kitty\" by Mike Henderson"
  photographer_1_link : "https://www.flickr.com/photos/mikehenderson/3750940230"
```

Ideally, I would like it if it was rendered like this:

"[Miss Kitty](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mikehenderson/3750940230)" by Mike Henderson

Any suggestions on how to do that? I've been googling around but I don't think I'm searching for the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Your `photographer_1` string needs to be rendered as HTML, which you signal to Rails by appending `_html` to the key (so it's now `photographer_1_html` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations)
2. You need to pass a parameter to this key, which would be the link you want inserted. Because links are the same in all locales, the link can be in your HAML. The parameters are passed as options in the `t()` method.

So you end up with:

  `# in en.yml
  photographer_1_html : "<a href='%{link}'>\"Miss Kitty\" by Mike Henderson</a>"`

`# in yourview.html.haml
  = t(:photographer_1_html,
      link:"https://www.flickr.com/photos/mikehenderson/3750940230")`

Comment: That is working!! Thanks.
Is there a way to specify that the url has target = "_blank" too ?

Comment: You would put that as an attribute in the HTML in the value in the YML file. Note also that the translatable part being the "A by B" part, you would probably want that to be another parametrizable YML string, something like `credits: "%{workname} by %{author}"`, and then in `es.yml`, that would be something like `credits: "%{workname} por %{author}"`

Comment: that worked too---thanks! here's an example of a string in my YML file:

``photographer_1_html : "\"<a href='%{link}' target='_blank'>Can I See the View, Too?</a>\" by Chris Lindamood"``